# Accessing a member variable is optimal or accessing a member function

Tags: c++

I would like to know, which one is more optimal accessing a member variable of a class through object pointer( as i am accessing it through friend function concept) or by using  getter and setter method of a class.

Comment: Could you post some code showing what you are trying to compare? "accessing a member variable of a class through object pointer" isn't very clear.

Answer (score 0):

To me, the best is an inline getter.

```
inline int GetValue() const {return Value;}
```

By the way, you can take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3017290/2307070)

Answer (score 0):

Typically, you'd write getters and setters inline, so there should be no overhead. Even with a separate definition, a good compiler should inline these calls through whole program optimization.

If this is not the case though, **profile** and see if performance is actually affected before you take any decision.

Note though that accessing members from outside (directly, from a `friend` or even getters and setters) breaks encapsulation. The `friend` option limits this to a specific class, so WRT this it's slightly better. If you must access those members, go with `friend`. If you have tons of friends, better go with getters/setters (at least you have a single access point, right). If performance is an issue (measurable), go with public members.

Comment: Hi Can give me some link for profiling, I am new into optimization part, I would be greatful if you could share :)

Comment: @add2c depends on the platform you're using. Just google for "profiling C++ applications on <platform>"

Comment: I have only one friend of that class actually this classe has some other member that belong to different class , so i thought to make use of friend and indirectly accessin this next level of class member( belong to some third class)