# Implement getters and setters in header file

Tags: c++, setter, getter

I have a simple question, is it a good practise to implement getters and setters in the header file, like this ?

```
class WebsocketSession : public boost::enable_shared_from_this<WebsocketSession>{
public:
    WebsocketSession(boost::asio::io_service& io_service, WebsocketServer& server);

    tcp::socket& getSocket() { return socket_; } // <---  This
private:
    tcp::socket socket_;
    WebsocketServer& server_;
};
```

Comment: duplicate of 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3017264/c-is-it-good-practice-to-make-getters-and-setters-inline

Comment: It's common practice! There's nothing wrong with it.

Comment: getters/setters are a waste of time.

Comment: @yngum _'getters/setters are a waste of time.'_ That's rubbish! Anything else leads to bad programming style.

Comment: There is no way to change this interface and it doesn't protect anything. It's a waste of time.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

**Advantage**

The getters and setters will be inlined so they will have no function overhead.

**Disadvantage**

You will be unable to make any changes to your getter and setter without having to recompile all code using your class. This is especially bad when the implementation of your class lies in a different DLL or .so file.

I personally do not like placing getters and setters in the header files.

Comment: "*The getters and setters will be inlined so they will have no function overhead.*" Is this still true for modern compilers, with link-time optimizations, etc.?